# How to retrieve the Xml file from Cachedirectory?

Tags: iphone, xml

Im new to Iphone development, I have locally saved one xml file and showing the details by using NSXmlParser(Which is stored in Resource folder). But, now i want to download new xml from url(from client side) and need to store that new xml file in Cache directory and also delete the xml file from resource folder. but i did not parse the new xml file from cache directory, How can i parse the new xml file from cache directory? Any one know this, please help me

Answer (score 0):

I've actually just recently written this functionality for one of my projects.  I'll share the code i used to do to save and write the XML file to my cache.

```
- (NSString *)XMLCacheFilePath 
{
    NSString *directory = @"/Library/Caches/XML/";
    NSString *fileName = [@"file" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"xml"];

    // Setup directory path
    NSString *homeDirectoryPath = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString *unexpandedDirectoryPath = [homeDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:directory];
    NSString *directoryPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                        [NSString stringWithString:[unexpandedDirectoryPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath]], 
                                                        nil]];

    // Setup file path
    NSString *unexpandedFilePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                        [NSString stringWithString:[unexpandedFilePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath]], 
                                                        nil]];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath isDirectory:nil]) {
        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath
                              withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                               attributes:nil
                                                    error:&error];                
    }

    return filePath;
}

- (void)saveXMLStringToDisk:(NSString *)xmlString
{
    NSError *error;

    [xmlString writeToFile:self.XMLCacheFilePath
                atomically:YES
                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                     error:&error];
}

- (NSString *)XMLStringFromDisk
{
    NSString *XMLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:self.XMLCacheFilePath
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                       error:nil];

    return XMLString;
}
```